# Работа с документом Excel с помощью PHP

Tags: php, excel

Как при помощи PHP создать документ Excel и записать в него переменные?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать документ в формате xml как обычный текстовый документ, записав в него нужную информацию:

1. Делается шаблон на Excel и сохраняется в формате xml.
2. С помощью PHP (или JavaScript если нужно на одном компьютере) открывается как текст  и меняется содержание.
3. Готовый текст записывается в новый файл с расширением xml или xls.

Comment: xls - бинарный формат. Вы его "как текст" пробовали открыть вообще?

Comment: если exel 2003 и старше(понимает xml) то формат не имеет значения.Если переименовать файл выведеный из excel в формате xml в xls то exel его откроет также как если открыть этот xml программой exel.
А содержание будет содержать настоящую электронную таблицу с оформлением, формулами шрифтами и.т.д.